# Unity 2017 + visual studio 2017 compile error with plugin waypointsSystem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have this error. What is happening right on my project when i run it is that the Waypoint System(plugin) doesn't work.

It's working in my co-workers Personal Computer, but not on my device. I compared most develop environment with partner environment. but I don't know where are different point between partner.

how can I solve this?

> CS0006
>   D:\Unity\Client\An2_Beta5\Temp\UnityVS_bin\Debug\Assembly-CSharp.dll
>
> CS0246
>   D:\Unity\Client\An2_Beta5\Assets\Scripts_World\WorldSpaceShip.cs
>
> CS0246
>   D:\Unity\Client\An2_Beta5\Assets\Scripts_World\WorldSpaceShip.cs

Comment: Where did you put that plugin? Can you show a it more details?

Answer (score 0):

Check your and your co workers build setting. May be it is on different targeting platform.